# Reset dscl UniqueID and PrimaryGroupID of root to 0 on Mac OS X

Tags: permissions, mac-osx, directory-services

Because of a very faulty script my root's PrimaryGroupID is 101 and UniqueID is 101. I have still an access to root, I can run sudo from my admin account, but the sudo and root do not have all the necessary rights obviously.

I can read dscl output, for instance:

```
dscl . -read /Users/root PrimaryGroupID
PrimaryGroupID: 101

dscl . -list /Users UniqueID
root 101

dscl . -list /Groups PrimaryGroupID
wheel 0
```

But I cannot change anything with dscl:

```
sudo dscl . -change /Users/root UniqueID 101 0
<main> attribute status: eDSPermissionError
<dscl_cmd> DS Error: -14120 (eDSPermissionError)
```

What is interesting, when I run:

```
dscl . -read /Groups/wheel GroupMembership
GroupMembership: root
```

How can I reset the UniqueID and PrimaryGroupID of the root to 0. I logged in Terminal through Mac OS X Installation DVD, I have a superuser with all the necessary rights there, but I did not figure out how to access the records of Directory Service from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make a backup of the user & group data; it's stored in the /Volumes/yourbootvolume/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default, so just copy that entire directory to someplace safe in case anything else goes wrong.  Once that's done, there are a couple of different ways to reset root's uid back to 0:

It's probably simplest to use a text editor: edit /Volumes/yourbootvolume/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/root.plist, look for a section like this:

```
<key>uid</key>
<array>
    <string>101</string>
</array>
```

and change the "101" to "0".  Warning: if you mess up the format of this file, you can render your system even more unusable than it is now.

The other option would be to use `dscl -f` to open the regular system's user files even though you're booted from the DVD instead.  Check to make sure you can access them with:

```
dscl -f /Volumes/yourbootvolume/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default localonly -read  /Local/Target/Users/root
```

It should print out the various properties of the root account, including "UniqueID: 101".  If that worked, you should be able to set it back with:

```
dscl -f /Volumes/yourbootvolume/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default localonly -change  /Local/Target/Users/root UniqueID 101 0
```

Comment: Thanks. I went for manual edit of the root.plist as the second approach complained about missing linked private framework.

Comment: A missing private framework seems rather strange (if moot at this point).  What version was the install DVD you used?